# External IP Address is refusing to connect in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i have created a VM instance. Now when i am trying to launch external ip address in new tab it is refusing connect
[image]

[image]

any suggestion??

Comment: you allowed 8888, not 80. Try using 35.227.92.94:8888

Comment: @Flyzzx its working now thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you have opened port 8888, so you should be connecting on your browser by

35.222.94.97:8888

If you want to open port 80, then  port 80 should be opened.